# How to subplot graphs that was produced by function in loop?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a method in my "DescriptiveStatistics" class:

```
def plot_histogram(self):
    values = self._aggregation()
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
    sns.distplot(values, bins=50)
    plt.xlabel(f"{self.agg}[{self.variable}]")
```

sns here is a seaborn package. And I'd like to plot 4 graphs in a loop(every loop is a new instance of the Class) in a dimension (2,2). The best results I get only like this:

```
aggs = ['sum', 'min', 'max', 'mean']

for agg in aggs:
    A = DescriptiveStatistics(df, 'Revenue', 'User_ID',agg=agg)
    A.plot_histogram()
```

I tried to paste plt.sublots in the loop before calling the method plot_histogram(), but it gives wrong results(graphs continuing to plot sequentially(not in dimension (2,2))

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up the Axes as a 2x2 array and then pass the required Axes object to your plotting function (don't set up a new figure in each call to `plot_histogram`) :

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 5))

def plot_histogram(self, ax):
    values = self._aggregation()
    sns.distplot(values, bins=50, ax=ax)
    plt.xlabel(f"{self.agg}[{self.variable}]")

for i,agg in enumerate(aggs):
    A = DescriptiveStatistics(df, 'Revenue', 'User_ID',agg=agg)
    A.plot_histogram(ax.ravel()[i])
```